# Equation rendering for question overview

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

When a question contains MathJax in the first few sentences, the question title/summary that is displayed on the landing page (for instance, physics.stackexchange.com) will try to render the equation. This is great if the ending `$` is within the character limit for the summary length.

But, as shown in the attached example, if the ending `$` or `$$` is outside the limit, you just get some ugly MathJax that doesn't help understand (and sometimes clouds) the summary.

[image: broken display]

Would it be possible to have the code that generates the summary here scan ahead if it ends in a `$` or `$$` section before it found the final markers? Either have it scan all the way to the end of the equation, or if the end doesn't come in the next `X` characters, have it stop at the opening markers?

After a few years, this again popped up on Physics Meta as an issue ([Mathjax rendering bug in Recent Questions page when excess content is replaced by ellipsis](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/mathjax-rendering-bug-in-recent-questions-page-when-excess-content-is-replaced-b)). It is also related to another recent request here ([Search results and MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281522/search-results-and-mathjax)). I'd like to bump it to see if it is just super low priority or if it had been forgotten about entirely (and it's likely both are true!)

Comment: Of course, I am all in favor of seeing this fixed, but I suspect that it is a big job and don't know when (or if) the team will get to it. Nice to see a suggested implementation that catches the obvious difficult cases, however. That will help.

Comment: Obviously it's going to be lower priority but I've noticed it a few times and figured I should post it. That example isn't terrible, but I've seen some that start "Consider: $$..." where it's nothing but MathJax gibberish to the end of the summary so it is not useful.