# Search results and MathJax

Tags: bug, search, mathjax

When doing a search, posts with MathJax code are wrongly formatted.

In this example https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=ce all the results look ugly. When taking a closer look at the first post, I notice that the first `$` is not regocnized by MathJax as a math-begin, while the second `$` (that should denote math-end) is taken as the beginning of math.

[image: screenshot]

Another example: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathrm

[image: screenshot]