# LaTeX rendering is sometimes wrong in questions list and search results

Tags: bug, search, question-lists, mathjax

When searching on a site with [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) enabled ([example](//stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=finding+the+distribution+)), I saw some [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) rendering issues: (and currently it's also in the [questions list on the site](//stats.stackexchange.com/questions))

> [image]

Even though the LaTeX rendering is fine when opening the [question](//stats.stackexchange.com/q/243219/12359):

> [image]

The LaTeX code is:

```
$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{$ \omega<0, \omega=1, \omega>3 $} \\[2ex]
-\omega + 1,  & \text{$ 0\le\omega<1 $} \\[2ex]
\omega^2 - 1,  & \text{$ 1< \omega \le 2 $} \\[2ex]
3 \omega,  & \text{$2 < \omega \le 3 $}
\end{cases}$
```

Comment: This is not questions list, it's search results.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281522/search-results-and-mathjax

Comment: @ShadowWizard I got it on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions . (Thanks for the edits)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmm maybe dupe indeed

Comment: Oh, forgot the /questions showing excerpt of the question. Still, most likely same root cause.