# LaTeX incorrectly parsed in search results

Tags: bug, search, mathjax

I noticed that sometimes LaTeX is incorrectly parsed in the search result pages. For example, the first result for https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=arma right now looks like this, where the end of the first math block is not recognized:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It is not exactly the same error. I found however this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281522/search-results-and-mathjax which apparently is the same bug (almost 5 years old and without any answer).

Comment: @user175348 that was an automated message produced by me voting to close this question as a duplicate of that question.